# Receiving radio box value in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 2 following radio boxes in a form,

```
 <label><input type="radio" onclick="this.form.submit()" name="shfaq<?php echo $i; ?>" value="1" id="radiobuttonsondazh_0" <?php if($result['live']==1) echo 'checked'; ?> />Po</label>
 <label><input type="radio" onclick="this.form.submit()" name="shfaq<?php echo $i; ?>" value="0" id="radiobuttonsondazh_1" <?php if($result['live']==0) echo 'checked'; ?> />Jo</label>
```

How can i recieve the value of the radio button once the form is posted (in PHP) and the radio name its not same for all results?

Comment: The name of these elements should be the same. Only the values should change. And then you can use `$_POST["radio-name"]` to get the selected value

Comment: The problem is that i dont want the name to be the same

Comment: But that's how HTML works. Otherwise they won't be connected and you can just use checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio button lets the users select only one of the available choice. It is grouped by the radio button name. When you post the form, you will get only one value for the radio group. Keep the name of the radio buttons same and you will get the correct value for that name (i.e 1 or 0).

Comment: The problem is that i have more than 1 line on my results from mysql and the name of radio can not be the same becouse when i change from Live or not live (i.e 1 or 0) how to send wich line i have change it the radio button on ?

Comment: one question. what you are trying to do with these radio button? User can select multiple values from list or can only select only one value? If user can select multiple values then use checkbox field instead of using radio buttons.

Comment: I get for example 10 results from mysql and any line have on or off to go live. So i think its multimple value on and off for each line

Comment: it means if you have 10 results then you will show 20 radio button, 2 for each. then you can follow the same method. give same name for each two radio buttons. Then it will represent the each result item from your db.

Comment: if you have 10 sites with on/off status, then you need to have 10 radio buttons with name as "site1/site2/site3/etc" and the value as 0,1. You need to know the sitename to get the value in the server end.

Answer (score 0):

The radio button name should be same. Like this:

```
<label><input type="radio" onclick="this.form.submit()" name="shfaq" value="1" id="radiobuttonsondazh_0" <?php if($result['live']==1) echo 'checked'; ?> />Po</label>
<label><input type="radio" onclick="this.form.submit()" name="shfaq" value="0" id="radiobuttonsondazh_1" <?php if($result['live']==0) echo 'checked'; ?> />Jo</label>
```

Then you can receive the value of the readio button in php like this:

```
<?php
  echo $_REQUEST['shfaq'];
?>
```

Comment: ARUN thank you for your answer but i dont want the name= to be same on all my lines :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish the radio buttons by their value, in your example:

```
<label><input type="radio" onclick="this.form.submit()" name="shfaq" value="shfaq<?php echo $i; ?>" id="radiobuttonsondazh_0" <?php if($result['live']==1) echo 'checked'; ?> />Po</label>
<label><input type="radio" onclick="this.form.submit()" name="shfaq" value="shfaq<?php echo $i; ?>" id="radiobuttonsondazh_1" <?php if($result['live']==0) echo 'checked'; ?> />Jo</label>
```

Then in your code you check `$_POST['shfaq']` to see which one was selected, either shfaq0 or shfaq1 (depends on your $i of course).

Comment: Jan Misker thank you for your answer but i dont want the name= to be same on all my lines :(

Comment: Ok sure, then you can not use radio buttons.

Comment: Read up on the basics of HTML radio buttons here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_radio.asp